# Qt + external library gaves glibc malloc(): memory corruption

Tags: qt, memory, glibc, corruption

I’m doing a gui app with Qt 4.8.5 and c++ on a fedora 18. For that I am using also some external libraries compiled with eclipse.

Until last week it worked all okey, I could call and use that external library functions with no problem.

The first error ocurred last week when a memorry corruption appeared with something like this (I can’t remember exactly all):

```
** glibc detected [...] malloc(): memory corruption: 0x10013ff8 ***
```

I clean and run qmake and nothing.. and then I run valgrand (I still don’t know what is that exactly for but it worked).

Today I got some error like this and did same and it worked but lately again I had:

```
*** glibc detected *** /home/sg/Documents/Projects/myApp/build-myApp-Desktop-Debug/myApp: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0986f260 ***
```

And valgrind did nothing so lookign for internet I saw that it could be fixed with a external valgrind so I follow this instructions: [Valgrind](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Using_valgrind_with_Qt_Creator)

And it solved my problem… BUT now my app runs well if I run it like the example (running vlagrind) but if I try to run it like I was doing before (Just run debug/release of myApp) then the glibc memorry corruption appears again… and that seems to be a very bad problem because ofc the .exe will not run …

so… any idea of the problem? The only difference on the external libraries this time is that they have a couple of get and sets more so there is no malloc or array or something like that new that could cause a memor acces problem

note: in the arguments line I had to put:

```
-q --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --leak-resolution=low ./myApp
```

with no supression because it gaved me an error… tried also with qt48 but the same.

Valgrind prints some things like this on the console:

```
==2848== Invalid write of size 4
==2848==    at 0x435CA6E3: pthread_mutex_init (in /usr/lib/libpthread-2.16.so)
==2848==    by 0x808A450: TLib::CSection::CSection() (Section.cpp:11)
==2848==    by 0x80773D6: CClass1::CClass1() (Class1.cpp:15)
==2848==    by 0x807C642: CClass2::CClass2() (Class2.cpp:21)
==2848==    by 0x807C800: CClass2::Initialize() (Class1.cpp:51)
==2848==    by 0x805A346: BaseWizard::BaseWizard(QWidget*) (basewizard.cpp:49)
==2848==    by 0x80523A2: main (main.cpp:26)
==2848==  Address 0x5b09f14 is 0 bytes after a block of size 292 alloc'd
==2848==    at 0x4008AAD: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:292)
==2848==    by 0x807C638: CClass2::CClass2() (Class2.cpp:21)
==2848==    by 0x807C800: CClass2::Initialize() (Class2.cpp:51)
==2848==    by 0x805A346: BaseWizard::BaseWizard(QWidget*) (basewizard.cpp:49)
==2848==    by 0x80523A2: main (main.cpp:26)

==2848== Invalid read of size 4
==2848==    at 0x438EBA44: std::string::_M_mutate(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.17)
==2848==    by 0x438EBC32: std::string::_M_replace_safe(unsigned int, unsigned int, char const*, unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.17)
==2848==    by 0x438EBCDB: std::string::assign(char const*, unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.17)
==2848==    by 0x438EBF16: std::string::operator=(char const*) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.17)
==2848==    by 0x80767B4: CClass3::CClass3() (Class3.cpp:39)
==2848==    by 0x807C6E2: CClass2::CClass2() (Class2.cpp:34)
==2848==    by 0x807C800: CClass2::Initialize() (Class2.cpp:51)
==2848==    by 0x805A346: BaseWizard::BaseWizard(QWidget*) (basewizard.cpp:49)
==2848==    by 0x80523A2: main (main.cpp:26)
==2848==  Address 0x5b15efc is 4 bytes after a block of size 48 alloc'd
==2848==    at 0x4008AAD: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:292)
==2848==    by 0x807C6D8: CClass2::CClass2() (Class2.cpp:34)
==2848==    by 0x807C800: CClass2::Initialize() (Class2.cpp:51)
==2848==    by 0x805A346: BaseWizard::BaseWizard(QWidget*) (basewizard.cpp:49)
==2848==    by 0x80523A2: main (main.cpp:26)
```

There are like 5 times more that information and then it throws the program. But if I run it without valdring then it says the glibc malloc() memory corruption. (And there have NOT been any changes about creating mallocs or frees or deletes or something like this).

note: About that references… main and basewizard are my classes on Qt (main.cppp and basewizard is the QWizard), and Class1,2,3 and CSection are from the external libraries

Thank you so much.

Comment: Show us  the `BaseWizard` constructor and where it is called from (in `main()`).

Comment: It's more or less solved. Definitely the problem is on the last update of the external library, so I can work with the previous version of the libraries while the person who did the library fix it. Thanks for all.